# Java NetBeans Compiling Error

Tags: java, compilation

When compiling my Code, it highlights this in red:

```
    Note: /Users/myName/NetBeansProjects/CardGame/src/cardgame/Hand.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

It still compiles and runs the program without fault (so far)... 
I was just curious to whether anyone would know whats causing it. Absolutely nothing appears on google and looking at my "Hand" Class, i can not see anything that should be causing an issue... :(

Comment: Have you tried adding the `-Xlint:unchecked` property when compiling the program to see a detailed explanation of the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Netbeans, right click on your project > Properties > Compiling > "Additional Compiler Options" and enter: `-Xlint:unchecked`.

Recompile and see what line is generating the warning.

Answer (score 0):

These are not compilation errors, they are some warnings. They say that you are not using generics or using them in a wrong way somewhere in your code.

For instance, something like this:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

should be:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Or type casting using generics: `List<String> lstString = (List<String>)object;`. Since OP hasn't post any code, it would be better for him/her to add the `-Xlint:unchecked` property when compiling the project.